# How to Debug NoClassDefFoundError (Gradle, Kotlin)

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin, noclassdeffounderror

With my kotlin project at Runtime I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/julianjarecki/latextemplates/lib/jtwig/RequireNodeParser
    at com.julianjarecki.latextemplates.lib.jtwig.RequireNodeParserProvider.<init>(RequireNodeParserProvider.kt:8)
    at com.julianjarecki.latextemplates.lib.jtwig.RequireExtension.configure(RequireExtension.kt:11)
    at org.jtwig.environment.EnvironmentFactory.create(EnvironmentFactory.java:60)
    at com.julianjarecki.latextemplates.lib.jtwig.LatexTemplate.getLatexRequireEnvironment(LatexParser.kt:76)
    at com.julianjarecki.latextemplates.lib.jtwig.LatexTemplate.access$getLatexRequireEnvironment$p(LatexParser.kt:68)
    at com.julianjarecki.latextemplates.lib.jtwig.LatexTemplate$template$2.invoke(LatexParser.kt:73)
    at com.julianjarecki.latextemplates.lib.jtwig.LatexTemplate$template$2.invoke(LatexParser.kt:68)
    at com.julianjarecki.latextemplates.lib.UpdatableLazy.getValue(UpdatableLazy.kt:17)
    at com.julianjarecki.latextemplates.lib.jtwig.LatexTemplate.getTemplate(LatexParser.kt)
    at com.julianjarecki.latextemplates.view.MainView$root$1$4$1$1$2.invoke(MainView.kt:133)
    at com.julianjarecki.latextemplates.view.MainView$root$1$4$1$1$2.invoke(MainView.kt:35)
    at tornadofx.NodesKt$onDoubleClick$1.handle(Nodes.kt:484)
    at tornadofx.NodesKt$onDoubleClick$1.handle(Nodes.kt)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
```

Indeed, when I look into my buil folder, RequireNodeParser.class is not where it is supposed to be.
The class is referenced in RequireNodeParserProvider like this:

```
package com.julianjarecki.latextemplates.lib.jtwig

import org.jtwig.parser.addon.AddonParserProvider
import org.jtwig.parser.parboiled.node.AddonParser
import com.julianjarecki.latextemplates.lib.jtwig.RequireNodeParser

class RequireNodeParserProvider : AddonParserProvider {
    override fun keywords(): MutableCollection<String> = mutableListOf(RequireKeywords.REQUIRE.token)
    override fun parser(): Class<out AddonParser> = RequireNodeParser::class.java
}
```

How do I even start debugging this Problem?

Edit 1 (Stacktrace of the ClassNotFoundException cause):

[image: Stacktrace of the cause]

Comment: Step One is to analyze the real error, which is the nested `ClassNotFoundException`. `ClassNotFoundError` is what you get every time you try to refer to a class whose lookup already failed before.

Comment: The way I understand it, for some reason the RequireNodeParser.kt file was not compiled, although it has been referenced, and that is the reason. But why was it not compiled? Or am I totally wrong here?

Comment: There are other options: its initialization may have failed. This is why it is critical that you inspect the root cause of the `ClassNotFoundError`, you may find an `ExceptionInInitializerError`, this one again having the actual exception that caused it to fail.

Comment: Shouldn't there still be a .class file in that case?
The stacktrace of the cause looks pretty much the same. I don't know how to begin to understand it. can you refer to any resources, that explain any possible causes?

Comment: Solved it - iun the end, the reason was embarrassingly simple: RequireNodeParser.java was java, not kotlin. But I had only applied the kotlin plugin in the gradle config.